# firebase serve, emulator port for hosting?

Tags: localhost, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I just added new Firebase project with the following in firebase.json:

```json
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5002
    },
```

I started it with `firebase serve`. And it serves hosting on port 5000 (instead of 5002):

```
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you think there's a bug in the Firebase CLI, post an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @Leo , I have updated my answer. This is not a bug and working as intended

Answer (score 6, accepted):

firebase.json file doesn't work with the the `firebase serve` command. You have to use the `firebase emulators:start` command.

If you want to keep using `firebase serve` then it should be use like in:

```
firebase serve --only hosting --port=5002
```

Comment: Just to not confuse others: I think you mean that the "emulators" part does not work with `firebase serve`.