# Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorisation to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: node.js, express, cors, httpclient

I have a little NodeExpress server and when I try to make a request to the server it returns a 403 error
I have installed `Cors` and used it  and tried with chrome browser and Postman as 2 clients and got the same denied error

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Answer (score 46):

I was having this having this problem with using `firebase serve` on `MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021), Apple M1 Pro, macOS Monterey 12.3`

**UPDATE:**

so apparently the reason was

> [macOS Monterey introduced AirPlay Receiver running on port 5000. This prevents your web server from serving on port 5000. Receiver already has the port.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829313/12555423)

so the solution proposed by [the answer quoted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829313/12555423), was to either turn off the [AirPlay Receiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay#Receivers), or to run your app on another port.

if you are running your app using firebase serve, You can change the port by following this approach:

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64858875/12555423)

> firebase.json file doesn't work with the the firebase serve command.
> You have to use the firebase emulators:start command.
>
> If you want to keep using firebase serve then it should be use like
> in:
>
> ```
> firebase serve --only hosting --port=5002
> ```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Not a sufficient answer, but I was able to bypass this by entering `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. I don't think this is the best answer, neither I am satisfied with it. I'll definitely come back later and update the answer once I find a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

for Chrome try this

[chrome://net-internals/#sockets](https://chrome://net-internals/#sockets)

you will be displayed tiny webpage like this:

[image]

click **[Flush socket pools]**

Answer (score 2):

just use another port e.g. 5100

```
"sampleApp": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5100",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had the same issue when developing FLASK application on Monterey and using Chrome.
A restart of Chrome always solved the issue. I suppose that not stopping the application properly is the root cause in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue. My stack was Node + Express

With this stack, above solution works as well.

All I had to do was to change the port number:

`app.listen(5000);` // does not work

`app.listen(8000);` // all good :)

Answer (score -3):

I was experiencing a similar outcome, and turning off Airplay Receiver helped me resolve the issue

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you explain how this can address the question? Your case is very specific, not related to the problem stated