# Access to localhost was denied - Docker Issue on mac brower

Tags: docker

I am just starting with docker, I setup docker in my mac, ran below command to launch and basic python image

```
$docker run -p 5000:5000 in28min/hello-world-nodejs:0.0.1.RELEASE
```

command ran successfull, but while tried reach the url its throwing below error:

```
*Access to localhost was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
-Reload
*
```

Using `docker run -p 80:80 nginx` then hitting localhost in a browser seems to work OK for me.

I refered this https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3214

Comment: I got the fix:

Whenever we run a container, it is part of an internal docker network called a bridge networl. By default, all the containers run under the bridge network, unless is port is exposed to outside.

command part 80:5000 means we are taking the port 5000 and mapping it to a host port 80(a port on the local machine), -p means publish container port 5000 to local host port 80.

By default the image i am using is getting deployed on 5000 container port. Thats why x:80 is not working, x:5000 is only working

Answer (score 0):

Please see this topic, is an issue on MACOS REF: [Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorisation to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913242/access-to-localhost-was-denied-you-dont-have-authorisation-to-view-this-page-h)

Try to use different port on host like 6000:

`$docker run -p 6000:5000 in28min/hello-world-nodejs:0.0.1.RELEASE`

Comment: I tried other ports as well:

This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:6000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT